# Python unittest - possible to keep failing until pass?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Let's say there is a test function that goes through a list of various numbers to test. These numbers are listed in increasing order such that once you get past a certain number (done through a loop), the results become acceptable and I can pass the test. (This means that all numbers BEFORE the passing number are failures). Now that I've found the acceptable number, I can stop the entire test regardless of whether there are more numbers in the list. Thus, I basically need a way to "fail until pass" using Python unittest. Is there a way to do this using built-in methods from unittest? I've pasted a code snippet to better communicate what I need to do.

```
def test_numbers(self):
    passing_number = 10     # can be any number randomly chosen in  number_list
    number_list = [8,9,10,11,12]   # example list of numbers to test
    for(number in number_list):
        # Do some operations with number...

        # Pass criteria - Not sure what to do here
        if(number == passing_number):
            # Then accept 'number' and stop the entire test.
```

Comment: Do you just want a break after your check for passing?

Comment: In the sense that I want to stop the test, but I don't want to actually use break (or something like it) because I hear that's bad practice.

Comment: What's the code you are actually testing?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot paste the actual code here. But the code snippet I pasted above shows what I'm trying to do in the generic sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by definition a unit test is an automated piece of code that invokes a unit of work in the system and then checks a single assumption about the behavior of that unit of work. **Single** is the key here.

If the test is supposed to fail for a given input, then the code unit passed the test. IMHO if you want to apply the test to a range of inputs and assure it passes for at least one of them, this loop should be placed at a code unit, not on the test case.

Comment: Unit tests dont have to test a single assumption, nor do they have to be automated...

Comment: I'm not saying mine is the more correct, but clearly we are using different definitions of the term "unit test". References?

Comment: Unit testing must only test the smallest possible of (reasonable) code. A method, for example, may make changes to data in several other places, you'd want to verify each of those worked. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292197(v=vs.71).aspx) is MSDN's article on the subject, though it could be clearer as it relates to our discussion.

Comment: I see, I'm using "automated" in the sense that it is not a "manual" test - the simple fact that you wrote a test makes it automated. Also, I'm using "unit test" in the theoretical sense - what a practical implementation calls "unit test" may be comprised of several tests. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I see the confusion. Might be best to try to avoid the word automated then, given that it has a specific meaning as it relates to testing.